# Delphi - Tokyo XE 10.2 RESTFUL Client Library Request/Response

Tags: rest, delphi, request, response

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Tutorial:_Using_the_REST_Client_Library_to_Access_REST-based_Web_Services

Worked through this code example to run a Req/Resp via Delphi Rest client library. Curious to know if through the example shown about giving values to request parameters can be dynamic?

The value is hardcoded in the example, and a TEdit Button is linked, but I do not see how we are able to pass value from TEdit input to the Request parameter for value.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can change the request parameter values from code. [Params](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequest.Params) property is just a collection of [TRESTRequestParameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameter) type items (the collection itself is of the [TRESTRequestParameterList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameterList) type). Write for example:

```
{ there seems to be only indexed access implemented for this
  collection, so to access the first parameter value write }
RESTRequest1.Params[0].Value := Edit1.Text;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping that would be possible. Was not sure if it should be done within the Value parameter in the IDE tool or within code.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, if that was limited just to the IDE setup, the whole concept would rely on precompiled parameter values which would make it unusable in practical usage. Actually, the code in this post shows just what is being setup by the IDE designer on your picture, nothing more than that. Of course, in code you must setup the values before you do the request.